# gooogle apps script getRange specific

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this code in google apps script

```js
var converter_row_csv = 1; 
var ROW_MAX_NUMBER = 10000000000; 
for (converter_row_csv = 2 ; converter_row_csv <ROW_MAX_NUMBER ; converter_row_csv ++){ 
  if (SourceSheet.getRange(converter_row_csv, 1).getValue() == "CONVERTER") { 
    converter_row_csv = converter_row_csv + 1; //go down 1 more rows to start gathering data break;
  } 
} // end for converter_row FOR LOOP
```

So, this code go find word "CONVERTER" in my sheet, down 1 rows and copy all info that contain data.

But i need now find word "CONVERTER" in my sheet, down 1 rows, **move 13 columns right** and copy all info same.

Comment: Are you looking for more clarification on the [`getRange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column) method?

Comment: I don't see anything about copying data in the code you provided. Also, I'm not sure I understand `down 1 rows and copy all info that contain data`. Can you clarify the expected outcome a bit, either by providing a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, or screenshots showing this expected outcome?

Comment: Yea sure, im try to read info in my Excel google, and i need to find a specific cell, not always at the same, this is the reason because this code find the word "CONVERTER" and count 1 down cell and copy the data that finded.

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, clearly showing the expected outcome?

Answer (score 0):

That code will run quite slowly because it is calling `Range.getValue()` in the inner loop. Try this pattern:

```
  const data = SourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  let result;
  let rowIndex;
  data.some((row, index) => {
    if (row[13 - 1] === 'CONVERTER') {
      result = row;
      rowIndex = index + 1;
      return true;
    }
  });
  if (result) {
    // result contains the data in the first row with 'CONVERTER' in column M
    // rowIndex contains the row number where it was found
  } else {
    // no row has 'CONVERTER' in column M (col 13)
  }
```